# should I use conda or pip in anaconda to install a python package?

Tags: python-2.7, pip, anaconda

after install anaconda I notice that it has its own pip:

```
$ which pip
/home/my_ubuntu/anaconda2/bin/pip
```

Now I want to install a new package, say lmdb. I use conda to install:

```
conda install lmdb
```

liblmdb.so and liblmdb.a have been installed under `/home/my_ubuntu/anaconda2/lib`. However, i cannot import lmdb under python console. It just says it cannot find lmdb.

I turn to install lmdb using pip. Now I can import lmdb:

```
>>> import lmdb
>>> lmdb.__file__
'/home/my_ubuntu/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lmdb/__init__.pyc'
```

My question is: what is the difference between conda and pip command? Why I can't import lmdb if using conda to install it?

Version info:
conda  4.4.8
pip (installed under conda)  9.0.1
conda list now gives two lmdb versions:

```
lmdb                      0.93                      <pip>
lmdb                      0.9.21               hf484d3e_1
```

Comment: Unrelated, but why are you using Python 2.7?  Unless you have a very good reason to, such as working on an old project, you should be using Python 3.

Comment: yep, you guessed correctly. I am working on an old project.